# Authentication with JWT Bearer doesn't work the debug says the problem is inside the GetToken() function

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, jwt, bearer-token

I've a code using JWT Bearer to authenticate some tokens as below.

```
private string GetToken()
    {
        var issuer = _factory.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwtSettings:Issuer");

        DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        var jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: issuer,
            claims: new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim("a claim", "a claim value")
            },
            expires: expiryDate,
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_factory.Configuration.GetValue<string> 
("JwtSettings:Secret"))),
                SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature
            )
        );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken);

    }
```

---

```
private HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        var client = _factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
        });

        var token = GetToken();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), $"Bearer {token}");
        return client;
    }
```

But it doesn't work and I don't have any idea cuz I'm new to C-sharp and .Net

It gives me the error of couldn't create the signature

Please Help.

Comment: Please post the exact error. But if I were to guess the issue may be that you say your token should be symmetrically signed with RSA-SHA256, but RSA is an asymmetric key algorithm (i.e. it needs 2 keys: one to sign and one to verify the signature). If that is the error, than use a symmetric algorithm like `SecurityAlgoritms.HmacSha256`.

Comment: @ckuri the error is about symmetric security algorithm. I think your solution is correct. I'm very new to backend development. the previous code is generating a token using rsa and inside ge token function I'm decoding it using rsa which should be changed to hmac. is it possible to keep the generation rsa and do something in the get token function?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have specified SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature which is asymmetric key algorithm which requires two keys (private and public key)

For code to work, change SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature to SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature